# Component's overlay doesn't disappear even after state changes in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, activity-indicator

Below is my code:

```
// Styling for the common loader
const loader = StyleSheet.create({
  centering: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    padding: 8,
    zIndex: 1005,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    opacity: 0.8
  },
});

// State
this.state = {
   animating: false
};

// Component
{
  this.state.animating ?
  <ActivityIndicator
    animating={this.state.animating}
    color="#8bcb43"
    style={loader.centering}
    size="large"
  />
    :
  null
}
```

I have attached the screenshot of how the loader looks when `this.state.animating` is **true** and when it is **false**.

[image: Loader when Animating is true][image: Loader disappears when animating is false but overlay doesn't disappear]

**I am surprised as to why the component doesn't disappear when `this.state.animating` is false. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.**

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I am struggling with the same thing at the moment..

Comment: @irruputuncu I have written an answer to help. I am not sure if it's the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this problem nine months ago when I was using [React Native 0.35.0](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.35/) and this is what I did back then as I didn't find any appropriate solution:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';

// Styling for the common loader
const loader = StyleSheet.create({
  centering: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    opacity: 0.8
  },

  hideIndicator: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -100,
    opacity: 0
  }
});

export default class Loader extends Component {

  render() {
    /* The reason for adding another activity indicator was to hide the first one */
    /* At the time of development, ActivityIndicator had a bug of not getting hidden */
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator
        animating={ this.props.animating }
        color="#8bcb43"
        style={ this.props.animating ? loader.centering : loader.hideIndicator }
        size="large"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**I toggle the style for the loading states.**

`style={ this.props.animating ? loader.centering : loader.hideIndicator }`

I am not sure if this problem still persists, but if you're facing the same issue then I hope this answer helps.